# How to make a video capture of both a VM Host and running virtual machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, video-capture

I have the following configuration:

- Windows 8 Hyper-V host;
- Windows 8 Guest;
- Windows 7 Guest.

What I want to do is a comparison video between Win 7 and Win 8 and how things have changed. For this I need video capturing software like Camtasia. However, I don't know if Camtasia or any other software supports the following feature:

I want to capture whatever I currently see on my monitor, including maximizing and switching between VMs. As far as I know, though, if I maximize one of the guest VMs, the video capturing software, which is running on the host, would record only the desktop of the Host. Is the only solution to just keep the guests not maximized or is there an alternative?